# How do you retrieve the video stream from Unity MRTK-WebRTC?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc, hololens

Right now, I have successfully managed the Web-RTC connections between the HoloLens and Unity. But now I would like to retrieve the video stream from HoloLens and perform some opencv algorithms. I am currently unsure how I can go about extracting the video stream?
Would greatly appreciate some help in this, really a newbie to all of this.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [VideoReceiver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/unity/unity-remotevideosource.html) component provided [VideoTrack](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.Unity.VideoReceiver.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_WebRTC_Unity_VideoReceiver_VideoTrack) property to receives video frames from the remote peer. Therefore, you can register to [I420AVideoFrameReady](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.RemoteVideoTrack.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_WebRTC_RemoteVideoTrack_I420AVideoFrameReady) or [Argb32VideoFrameReady](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.RemoteVideoTrack.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_WebRTC_RemoteVideoTrack_Argb32VideoFrameReady) event with a callback method to handle every new video frame received.